# calling function in external js file

Tags: php, jquery

test .php

```
<div id="widget_dta"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    init_widget('john','robert');
</script>
```

widget.js

```
 (function() {

 // Localize jQuery variable
 var jQuery;

 /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
   if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
script_tag.setAttribute("src",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js");
if (script_tag.readyState) {
  script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
      if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
          scriptLoadHandler();
      }
  };
} else { // Other browsers
  script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
}
// Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||   document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
// The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
jQuery = window.jQuery;
main();
}

/******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
// Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
// new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
// Call our main function
main(); 
}

/******** Our main function ********/
function main() { 
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     function init_widget(fname,lname) {
        $('#widget_dta').append('<p class="fname">first name :'+fname+'</p><p class="lname">last name :'+lname+'</p>');
   }
}); 
 }

 })();
```

error : I am getting this error "ReferenceError: init_widget is not defined". can anyone help where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

i think the `script.js` file is not loading properly. if its loading then the function should work as expected.

are you referencing the complete path of script in your script.js call? like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="some-domain.com/path/widget.js"></script>
```

try opening that file from page source and see if its loading the correct js file?

its always best practice to use `wp_enqueue_script` function for loading js files.

Comment: In widget.js file i was adding the jquery library. when it is loading js file ,library is adding in <head> section.

Comment: when i give the jquery library directly instead of adding from js file,the code is working fine.

Comment: you should use jquery library in seprate file then. plus maybe you are declaring that function above jquery codes in widget.js file ?

Comment: Thanq,my task is i need to include jquery library from widget.js file.But my function is not executing in js file.

Answer (score 1):

Your `init_widget` function is not visible from within `test.php`.

You must give your `init_widget` function global visibility:

```
/******** Our main function ********/
function main() { 

  window.myutils = window.myutils || {}; //Create a little namespace for your own functions so that they are not all global.

  //We dont need the jQuery on ready block here. You should assume that whoever calls init_widget will wait for the page to be ready first before calling.
  window.myutils.init_widget = function(fname,lname) {
        var $ = jQuery; //convenience so we can still use $ here instead of writing out jQuery all the time.
        $('#widget_dta').append('<p class="fname">first name :'+fname+'</p><p class="lname">last name :'+lname+'</p>');
  };
}
```

And then in your `test.php` file you'll need to do this:

```
<div id="widget_dta"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        window.myutils.init_widget('john','robert');
    });
</script>
```

Your `widgets.js` file should just define all the functions that are possible to call straight away. Only the code that actually needs to *use* the functions should then wait for a jQuery on-page-ready event to fire first before trying to use any of the widget functions.

Comment: Thank you for helping.Still not displaying any data in browser and also I am getting this error "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Comment: @user123 Ah okay, I thought you were doing this from within a wordpress theme which already had jQuery. So the easiest way to get around that is to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` into test.php before the widget.js script line. That will load jQuery first and then execute your function.

Comment: I need to call that jquery library with in widget.js file.My issue got solved.